# Mac OS X exported .app won't run

Tags: macos, xcode6, export

I am adding functionality to an existing OS X application. I can run the app within Xcode (6.1) just fine. However, when I archive the application, then click "Export...", then select "Export as a Mac Application" (I don't have an account to sign with), then try to run the resulting .app file, I get a problem report saying my app can't be opened because of a problem:

"Check with the developer to make sure MyApp works with this version of OS X. You may need to reinstall the application. Be sure to install any available updates for the application and OS X."

The base SDK of my project is 10.10. The OS X deployment target is also 10.10. My machine is running OS X 10.10. Anyone know what could be going wrong? Is my exporting procedure wrong? Any incite is much appreciated.

Comment: Try checking the error report.  There should be something there that tells you what is wrong.